# calculating with dictionary keys

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate the percentage difference in two columns. I have stored the values in two different dictionaries and calculating the percentage difference. The result is stored in a value = pct_change.

I then want to add it to a list, so i counts how many of the values that had a percentage increase and how many had a percentage decrease. Is it possible to create a new dictionary, store the pct_change as a key, and append the key in the new dictionary? After the loop then counting the number of keys in the dictionary?
I will post my current code below. Note that I am aware of the many defined variables that i am not using.
I hope someone can help me out

```
Sub benchmark()

Const NETSCONT_SHT3 = "D"
Const NETSCONT_SHT4 = "I"
Const NETSEXP_SHT4 = "H"


Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow, iTargetRow As Long, iCopyRow As Long, NbCont_SHT3 As Long, AmCont_SHT3 As Double
Dim NbCont_SHT4 As Long, AmCont_SHT4 As Double, NbResults As Integer, AmResult As Double, pct_change As Double
Dim msg As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim count As Long, countWB As Integer
Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet
Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim r As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("BrokerSelect")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("ContributionSplitReport")
Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("ContributionExceptionReport")

Dim dict As Object, dictEXP As Object, sKey As Double, ar As Variant
Dim sEXP As Double, arEXP As Variant

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictEXP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' pct change in expected and actual cont
iLastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.count, NETSCONT_SHT4).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 18 To iLastRow
    sKey = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSCONT_SHT4)
    sEXP = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSEXP_SHT4)
    If sKey <> "0" Then
        pct_change = (sKey - sEXP) / sKey
        MsgBox (pct_Change)
    Else

    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: "I have tried to store the values in two different dictionaries and calculating the percentage difference" - can you show us that code? In the current snippet, you create the dictionaries, but then don't do anything with them.

Comment: I try to calculate the percentage change in the if statement. I use the keys there

Comment: You don't store the values in the dictionaries though.

Comment: I understand that your dictionaries are for the future use... For now, try putting a Stop in your code, `pct_change = (sKey - sEXP) / sKey : Stop` and see what values your variables took. Just move the cursor over them... What do they show?

Comment: It shows the right values. skey = 6000, sEXP = 5500

Comment: oh. I made a stupid mistake. I can see that i did not type the variable name correct in the message box.. it is working now.. Sorry

Comment: However, do you know how i can store a list with the values that have an percentage increase, and a list for the decrease and adds up a list with how many are in each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your last request, please replace

```
MsgBox (pct_Change)
```

with

```
 Dim d As Long, dE as Long
    If pct_Change > 0 Then
      dict.Add d, pct_Change: d = d + 1
    ElseIf pct_Change < 0 Then
      dictEXP.Add dE, pct_Change: dE = dE + 1
    End If

  'finally:
  Debug.Print dict.Count, dictEXP.Count, dictEXP.Items(2)
```

Comment: i get an error. Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. I get the error in line: dict.add pct_change

Comment: @lass9509: Refresh, please the page ant test it now.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like it is doing something, but it is not working as it should.. In my document there are 25 cases where the difference is more than 0. The msgbox only finds 13.

Comment: Try it now, please. If the 'percentage' would be the same, it counted inside the same key... Please, refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you! it is working now!  what does the "Debug.Print dict.Count, dictEXP.Count" do?

Comment: It allows you to see the results in `Immediate Window`. Try pressing Ctrl + G being in VBE (Visual Basic Editor) and see the results (total number of dictionary keys and an example of the second key value)...